# WiFi internet connectivity issue iPhone 8

Tags: iphone, wifi, time-capsule, internet

Connected to AirPort Time Capsule 802.11ac (network name BZ), which is connected to a new cable modem (just moved to new building/ISP). Internet works fine on other devices (MacBook, tablet). iPhone 8 (iOS 11.4) will connect but says no internet. Airport utility shows active internet connection ([see picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0xG2.png)).

I tried restarting phone, forgetting network, and reset network preferences to factory defaults. [Still no internet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mS00L.jpg). iPhone will connect to other WiFi networks and gets internet with no problem. Any ideas? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Solved myself--Reset default settings on Time Capsule. Setting router mode to DHCP and NAT seemed to be the critical change.